# Difference between -CAfile and -trusted in OpenSSL verify

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, openssl, x.509, trust

`openssl verify` can be executed with both flag `-CAfile <FILE>` and `-trusted <FILE>`. The explanations from [OpenSSL 1.1.1 manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-verify.html):

```
-CAfile <FILE>
A file of trusted certificates. The file should contain one or more certificates in 
PEM format.

-trusted <FILE>
A file of trusted certificates, which must be self-signed, unless the -partial_chain 
option is specified. The file contains one or more certificates in PEM format. With 
this option, no additional (e.g., default) certificate lists are consulted. That is, 
the only trust-anchors are those listed in file. This option can be specified more 
than once to include trusted certificates from multiple files. This option implies 
the -no-CAfile and -no-CApath options. This option cannot be used in combination with 
either of the -CAfile or -CApath options.
```

They seem to do the same thing. I would assume that `-CAfile` also excludes the default certificates but if not, then `-CAfile` and `-no-CAfile` together (odd combination) should be the same as `-trusted`. Both `-CAfile` and `-trusted` have to contain certificates and even though it literally states in `-trusted` that they have to be self-signed, I would assume the same for those in `-CAfile`.

What is the difference between these and why isn't `-CAfile` enough to cover what `-trusted` achieves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'standard' OpenSSL truststore (used by most commandline operations, and most programs using the libraries) has *two* parts: a file (containing any practical number of certs) and a directory containing any number of files using hashnames (each containing exactly one cert), and *each* of them has a default (although on many systems one of the defaults is empty, so you don't notice it). `-CAfile` sets only the file, and `-CApath` only the directory, so you can combine an explicit CAfile with the default CApath or the default CAfile with an explicit CApath -- if you want to, although it's likely just confusing for most people. `-trust` (used by commandline `verify` *only*) replaces/overrides *both* of them -- as stated it's equivalent to `-no-CAfile -no-CApath` in 1.1.0 up (before that, those options didn't exist and if you wanted to suppress CAfile or CApath separately you had to provide an empty file or nonexistent or empty directory).

It's imprecise to say that the truststore 'must' contain only self-signed certs, which are the 'standard' (or at least usual) form for root CAs -- which are the ones you normally want to trust (and validate against). The actual case is that the truststore *can* contain both self-signed and other-signed certs, but normally (and always through 1.0.1, for people with long memories) only a self-signed cert in the truststore is *accepted as a trust anchor* and used to validate/verify the chain; if you use `-partial_chain` on 1.0.2 up then an other-signed cert is accepted as anchor. Although other-signed certs in the truststore normally are not sufficient to *validate* a chain, they *are* used if needed to *build* the chain in either case, which can be useful -- although it can also cause trouble when it leads people to think that e.g. a server is sending a chain that should be validated by other reliers, when in fact it isn't. The (building and) validation logic is the same regardless of whether the truststore content comes from CAfile-or-default plus CApath-or-default or from trusted.

Comment: But `-partial_chain` could have existed without `-trusted`, so what does `-trusted` bring to the table? Sounds like it disables any explicit or default ca file or path in one go, so that `-trusted <FILE>` is really just a short cut to `-CAfile <FILE> -no-CApath`?

Comment: Yes, precisely that. It's a shorthand to say "only these", which is really handy for automated tasks that run for years and should not pick up additional trust anchors because someone changes a file somewhere.

Comment: @fast-reflexes not quite; `openssl` commandline was created largely as a test and debugging tool, although some of its functions have evolved to be more generaly useful. `-trusted` uses a different part of the internal (library) API than `-CAfile/path`, and being able to test both is useful, although (absent bugs) they produce equivalent results.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 maybe too nitty-gritty but what is this other part meant for and what does it offer that the other doesn't? this should be in the docs!